# Error while sending e-mail with phpmailer

Tags: email, office365, phpmailer

I'm having this error while using phpmailer to send e-mails.

2022-11-28 11:29:32 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signatureerror:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature [C:\Apache24\htdocs\cursoCompletoPHP7\aula87\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 470]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signatureerror:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature

The credentials that i'm using are correct. The mail server is office365.

I have the same application running in my computer, with the same php/apache instalation, same mail server, same credentials and it's working just fine, but in the production server, it stop working about 2 weeks ago (it was working fine and it suddenly stopped).

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?

Thanks for the help!

I've tried using this application in another machine in the production network. It didn't work.

Comment: I can't post the credentials from the mail server here, but this is the code I'm using:

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,
                                          'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                          'allow_self_signed' => true));
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->Username = $remetente;
$mail->Password = $senha;
$mail->From = $remetente;
$mail->FromName = $remetente;
$enviado = $mail->Send();

Comment: Most likely your CA certificates are outdated, as per [the PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure). Also, don't disable certificate verification – fix your server instead. Don't post code in comments; it's largely unreadable: add it to your question instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.